# Цикл представляющий собой чек

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь с задание, вот задание Цикл представляющий собой чек. То есть ввод кода товара и количества - показ названия и суммы за данный товар, а так же общей суммы. Подсчет осуществляется по нажатию на определенный символ, обозначающий конец ввода.
А вот мои наработки, исправьте, что не правильно и скажите как сделать, что бы он количество умножал на цену товара

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "ru");
    int code, amout, N;
    do {
        cout << "Введите код товара: ";
        cin >> code;
        switch (code)
        {
        case 1250:
            cout << "Хлеб " << " 10\n";
            break;
        case 1251:
            cout << "Молоко " << " 14,50\n";
            break;
        case 1252:
            cout << "Картошка " << " 6\n";
            break;
        case 1253:
            cout << "Огурцы " << " 17\n";
            break;
        case 1254:
            cout << "Помидоры " << " 38\n";
            break;
        case 1255:
            cout << "Кукуруза " << " 6\n";
            break;
        case 1256:
            cout << "Арбуз " << " 13,60\n";
            break;
        case 1257:
            cout << "Дыня " << "23\n";
            break;
        case 1258:
            cout << "Петрушка " << "3\n";
            break;
        case 1259:
            cout << "Лимон " << "8\n";
            break;
        case 1260:
            cout << "Лайм " << "45\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Такого кода не существует." << endl;
        }
    } 
    while (code);
    {
        cout << "Введите кол-во товара: ";
        cin >> amout;

        cout << "Для расчета нажмите N: ";
        cin >> N;
    }


}
```

Comment: Можно пример выходного файла?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct ItemInfo
{
    string name;
    float price;
    ItemInfo(string str, float p)
    {
        name = str;
        price = p;
    }

};
enum eItems
{
    NOSET = 0,

    BREAD = 1250,
    MILK = 1251,
    LIMON = 1259,
    LIME = 1260,

};

std::map<eItems, ItemInfo*> mDataBase;

void init()
{
    mDataBase[BREAD] = new ItemInfo("Хлеб", 10.0f);
    mDataBase[MILK] = new ItemInfo("Молоко", 41.4f);
    mDataBase[LIMON] = new ItemInfo("Лимон", 78.81f);
    mDataBase[LIME] = new ItemInfo("Лайм", 11.92f);
}
void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "ru");
    init();
    int code = 0;

    float suma = 0.0f;
    int count = 0;

    char exitChar = 0;
    while(1)
    {       
        cout << "Введите код товара: ";
        cin >> code;        
        if(code == exitChar)
            break;
        ItemInfo* ptr = mDataBase[static_cast<eItems>(code)];
        if(ptr)
        {
            cout << ptr->name << " " << ptr->price << endl;
            cout << "Введите кол-во товара: ";
            cin >> count;

            if(count > 0)
            {
                suma += ptr->price * count;
            }
        }
    }




    if(suma > 0.001f)
    {
        cout << "Итого: " << suma << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как пример:

```
case 1250:           
  cout << "Хлеб " << 10 * amout;
  cout << "\n";
  suma += 10 * amout; 
break;
```

Comment: мне нужно что бы он по нажатию определённой кнопки посчитал общею сумму

Comment: Значит, создайте отдельную структуру данных для хранения товаров и их цен. Отдельно сохраняйте количество каждого товара. По итогам всё и обсчитывайте.

Comment: В начале декларируем «suma» как «double» и равную «0». Меняем «case» согласно моему примеру. При нажатии «N» -  cout << suma;

Comment: я сделал, вот так?
case 1250:
   cout << "Хлеб " << "10 гривен";
   cout << "\nДля продолжения нажмите h\n";
   cin >>h;
   suma = 10 * amout;
   cout << suma << " гривен - общая сумма за " << amout<< " единиц\n";
   break;

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа этого.
Это черновой вариант, писал на коленке. Вам стоит добавить ещё различных проверок.
Но лучше надо было бы создать структуру..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // setlocale(0, "ru");
    int code, amout;
    char N;
    double sigma = 0.;
    double cur = 0.;

    do
    {

        do
        {

            cout << "Введите код товара: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.sync();
            cin >> code;

            switch (code)
            {
                case 1250:
                    cout << "Хлеб " << " 10\n";
                    cur = 10.;
                    break;
                case 1251:
                    cout << "Молоко " << " 14,50\n";
                    cur = 14.5;
                    break;
                case 1252:
                    cout << "Картошка " << " 6\n";
                    cur = 6.;
                    break;
                case 1253:
                    cout << "Огурцы " << " 17\n";
                    cur = 17.;
                    break;
                case 1254:
                    cout << "Помидоры " << " 38\n";
                    cur = 38.;
                    break;
                case 1255:
                    cout << "Кукуруза " << " 6\n";
                    cur = 6.;
                    break;
                case 1256:
                    cout << "Арбуз " << " 13,60\n";
                    cur = 13.;
                    break;
                case 1257:
                    cout << "Дыня " << "23\n";
                    cur = 23.;
                    break;
                case 1258:
                    cout << "Петрушка " << "3\n";
                    cur = 3.;
                    break;
                case 1259:
                    cout << "Лимон " << "8\n";
                    cur = 8.;
                    break;
                case 1260:
                    cout << "Лайм " << "45\n";
                    cur = 45.;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Такого кода не существует.\n";
                    code = 0;
            }
        } while ( code == 0 );

        cout << "Введите кол-во товара: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cin >> amout;

        sigma += amout * cur;

        cout << "Для расчета нажмите N: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cin >> N;
    }
    while ( N != 'N' );

    cout << "Сумма: " << sigma << "\n\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct good
{
    float price;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    // <ID товара, товар>
    std::map<size_t, good> goods =
    {
        { 1250, { 10.00, "Хлеб" } },
        { 1251, { 14.50, "Картошка" } }
    };

    for( auto const it : goods )
    {
        std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second.name << " (" << it.second.price << " руб.)\n";
    }

    // <ID товара, кол-во>
    std::map<size_t, size_t> cheque;

    size_t id, amount;
    while( 1 )
    {
        std::cout << "Введите код товара, 1 для получения чека, 0 для выхода:\n";
        std::cin >> id;
        if( id <= 1 )
        {
            break;
        }

        if( !goods.count( id ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Неправильный код " << id << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Введите количество:\n";
            std::cin >> amount;
            if( cheque.count(id) )
            {
                cheque[id] += amount;
            }
            else
            {
                cheque[id] = amount;
            }
        }
    }

    if( id == 1 )
    {
        float sum = 0.0;
        for( auto const it : cheque )
        {
            // здесь можно распечатать каждый пункт чека
            sum += it.second * goods[it.first].price;
        }
        std::cout << sum;
    }
}
```